# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project Custom Action - Access rights error during installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, custom-action

I created a Visual Studio 2010 setup project, added my application's output and then I created a c# library class with a class decorated with RunInstaller . I added that class library output to the setup project and then added that output do custom actions view: commit and install action.

I tried to start the setup (with Administrator rights) and at some point of installation it tells me "Error writing into the file CustomAction.dll. Make sure you have access rights to the directory."

The installer class is the following:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class WriteFileCustomAction : Installer
{
    public override void Install(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\tmp\testInstall.log", "Install");
        base.Install(savedState);

    }

    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\tmp\testCommit.log", "Commit");
        base.Commit(savedState);
    }
}
```

What is the problem??

Comment: The setup works fine if I don't add the CustomAction, and the application folder path is C:\TestFolder\Test . It's a folder that is accessible (full access) from Administrators and Users.

Comment: After a hour of retries, I deleted the project, reinserted all things and the custom action, and all went fine. I thing something was corrupt in the previous project. Thanks